GLM with canonical link: Why linear regression over the natural parameter?
So I've been wondering why it is "natural" to extend linear models where we assume $Y\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ and try to fit $E[Y|X]=X\beta$ to generalized linear models where we assume $Y_i\sim P_{\theta_i,\phi a_i}$ for $$P_{\theta_i,\phi a_i}(t)=f_0(t;\phi a_i)\exp\left(\frac{\theta_i t-K(\theta)}{\phi a_i}\right)$$
I thought about it in two different ways, and I don't know whether one of this is accurate or not:

My first intuition was to think that $\theta_i$ is the (only?) parameter such that the log-density of $Y$ is linear on it, the same way $\mu$ was if $Y\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$. So that GLM with canonical link is equivalent to linear regression over normality assumption. But why is this log-linearity interesting in general, and how does it relate to point 2 of my question?

We search a regression function on X that is a composition of a trainable linear one with a fixed arbitrary different one, which is essentially what we do in most even more advanced models. So we want that $E[Y|X]=h(X\beta)$ for some function $h$, and we know that if $h=(K')^{-1}$ then $E[Y]=g^{-1}(\theta)$ so we just make $\theta=X\beta$ and then predict by taking $h$. So this is the most natural choice to the question of what regression function to pick whenever we have a exponential dispersion assumption on the data?


But even this doesn't seem quite convincing to me. What are reasons that justify this canonical link GLM. I'm aware that it is just a definition as many other possible and that it has to be checked wether the fit it produces is good or not, and I don't search an universal explanation of why this works. I just want to know why this is a natural generalization of linear models, even if it didn't ever work.
